# Issue with Parse.com custom webhook (to external URL on our servers)

Tags: parse-platform, webhooks

I am having issues getting Parse.com's webhook to work. I've created a webhook with an HTTPS URL on our application web server to trigger on the "afterSave" event of the "_User" class. The intent here is to let our own server know when a new user has registered via Parse on the website or the mobile app.

Looking at the webserver logs I can see that the URL is definitely being POSTed to when a new user is added. The issue is that there are no data being POSTed with the request. I've looked at the POST (form) data and the querystring data and it is always completely empty. What I am expecting is some sort of JSON data with details about the user that was just added or updated. Looking at the parse.com logs show that the request was sent, it shows the data I assume that I *should have* received, and it shows 'success' for the external POST, but I still get no data with the request on our server.

Surely I am missing something or doing something wrong... does anyone have ideas or advice?

Answer (score 0):

For future explorers who encounter this same issue...

Figured it out. Parse.com is posting the data as "multipart/form-data" and my lib was not expecting that. Derp!